# Rails "undefined method for ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this models:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :tickets
    has_many :movies, through: :tickets

end


class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :students, through: :tickets
    belongs_to :cinema

end


class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :movie, counter_cache: true
    belongs_to :student

end


class Cinema < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :movies, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :students, through: :movies

    has_many :schools, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :companies, through: :yard_companies

end


class School < ActiveRecord::Base 

    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :cinema, counter_cache: true

end


class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :movie, counter_cache: true
    belongs_to :company

end


class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :student

end


class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :teachers
    has_many :movies, through: :teachers

    has_many :contracts
    has_many :students, through: :contracts

end
```

If I write this in my **movies_controller.rb**:

`@students = @movie.cinema.companies.students.all`

I have this error:

**undefined method 'students' for #Company::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000007f13d88>**

If instead I write this:

`@students = @movie.cinema.companies.find(6).students.all`

it shows me the correct students in my select_collection.

**How to better understand this process?**

**UPDATE**:

I need the collection_select of every students in companies of a cinema of this movie.

How to write?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described by [Nermin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31409907/385532) you're trying to request a collection of children, from a collection of children.

You could use `collect` to gather the students from the companies along the lines of:

```
@movie.cinema.companies.collect(&:students).flatten.uniq
```

But I think you would do better to add a scope to your Student model along the lines of:

```
scope :for_companies, ->(_companies) {joins(:companies).where(company: _companies)}
```

Called with `Student.for_companies(@movie.cinema.companies)`

Disclaimer: untested, but should be a starting point!

Comment: I'm trying, @Matt. Thanks for your precious answer. But in the collection_select for the first solution how to retrieve the list? I'm using this: `<%= f.collection_select(:student_id, @students, :id, :name_with_surname, options = {:include_blank => true, :prompt => true}) %>`

Comment: @JohnSam that looks fine, but how are you filling the `@students` variable?

Comment: With this: `@students = @movie.cinema.companies.collect(&:students)` in `movies_controller` under `def new`. How to fill the collection with the solution of `.collect` method that you explain to me?

Comment: @JohnSam You may need `.flatten.uniq` on the collect. Have amended the answer. Try that, if it fails post the error.

Comment: It works! Because I think now the Array is of course flatten. But one problem now: N+1 query! Bullet detects the n+1 query problem. How to solve? Bullet says to me to add `includes(:students)` and `includes(:companies)` but where in this: `@students = @movie.cinema.companies.collect(&:students).flatten.uniq`?

Comment: @JohnSam You should head down the scope route, the second option I suggested. It is much cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: Ok, I will try it, but about performance in this article he says not good about scopes: http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/06/23/how-to-preload-rails-scopes/ Is him right? Why in terms of performances, you say that scopes (or associations) are better than the collect's solution?

Comment: @JohnSam You can include related models in your scopes so that they preload and avoid his n+1 scenario. He explains it only a few paragraphs from the top.

Comment: Dear @Matt, what means your code: `->(_companies) {joins(:companies).where(company: _companies)}`. Specifically what are these "_" underscores?

Comment: @JohnSam Mostly just for clarity to differentiate between the `companies` method that would exist for that model. Rails should be smart enough to scope it correctly but I like to be very explicit. You don't need them :)

Comment: It anyway doesn't work: he says: "students.company column doesn't exists".

Comment: It doesn't work because the final query is with `WHERE "students"."company_id" IN...` instead of `WHERE "contracts"."company_id" IN`. How to fix?

Comment: Ah, you'll probably want to change to `where('contracts.company_id' => @companies)`

Comment: I will mark this answer as "The one". But, there is a big BUT: I have to write my own "SQL QUERY" fragment? And where is all the Rails's smartness, intelligence?

Comment: @JohnSam You aren't writing any sql, you're writing a rails scope. Scopes are quite normal and very worth investigating further.

Answer (score 6):

`@students = @movie.cinema.companies.students.all` to explain why this throws error

`@movie.cinema` will give you cinema of the movie

`@movie.cinema.companies` will give you a list of companies for that cinema as an `ActiveRecord_Association_CollectionProxy`

Then when you call `students` on the `CollectionProxy` of companies via `@movie.cinema.companies.students` it throws an error because `CollectionProxy` has no such method.

`@students = @movie.cinema.companies.find(6).students.all` will work because you get a list of companies, then from that list you find a single company with id 6 and list all students for that single company.

Comment: Might be useful to include some `collect` examples for how to actually get all of the students from a collection of companies.

Comment: I need the collection_select of every students in companies of a cinema of this movie.

How to write?