# Ruby Delete multiple objects by association

Tags: ruby

My app needs to destroy all of the teams that have fewer than two members.

This method seems to be working, but I'm hoping to "rubify" it to one line if possible.

```
  @consultancy.teams.reverse.each do |team|
    team.destroy if team.users.count < 2 
  end
```

I'm trying to do something more like the following, but I'm getting an error for the reject! method.

```
@consultancy.teams.reject!{|x| x.users.count < 2}

NoMethodError: undefined method `reject!' for #<Team::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000003f72850>
```

.delete_all also throws an error.

```
@consultancy.teams.select{|x| x.users.count < 2}.delete_all

NoMethodError: undefined method `delete_all' for #<Array:0x0000000b72dcf0>
```

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: What error are you getting with `reject` and `delete_all`?

Comment: Good point.  I edited the question to include the error messages.

Comment: This question should help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409792/rails-undefined-method-for-activerecord-associations-collectionproxy

Basically, `@consultancy.teams` is not an array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`select` acts on arrays, but `delete_all` is an active record relation method.

You could do

```
@consultancy.teams.select{|x| x.users.count < 2}.map(&:delete)
```

But a better way might be to do the count select as part of the query.

```
@consultancy.teams.joins(:users).group('teams.id').having('count(users.id) < 2').destroy_all
```

Comment: Last part of the answer is what I'd write. Nice!

Comment: I'm curious why you both prefer the second approach.  What's the advantage?

Comment: Most of the "heavy lifting" is being done by the database, not by the application, and database operations always provide better performance.  For example `@consultancy.order(:name)` brings back all records in name order, `@consultancy.sort_by(&:name)` brings back all records, converts to an array, and then sorts the array by the `name` attribute.  If you find you're doing array operations it's always worthwhile to see if there's a SQL equivalent command.